# YOLOv4 on tensorRT INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot find binding of given name: nmsed_classes

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, tensorrt, yolov4, jetson-xavier

I have an issue while trying to run my code based on yolov4.engine that I generated from my onnx file, and I get this error:

```
[E] [TRT] INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot find binding of given name: num_detections

[E] [TRT] INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot find binding of given name: nmsed_boxes

[E] [TRT] INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot find binding of given name: nmsed_scores

[E] [TRT] INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot find binding of given name: nmsed_classes
```

I am running this on jetson AGX Xavier Dev Kit and the code works fine on my host machine, i got the error only at the moment when i run it on my jetson card.

on my host machine i have :
Tensorrt 7.2.3-1+cuda11.1

on my jetson AGX Xavier:
Tensorrt 7.1.3-1+cuda10.2 it was installed with last jetpack 4.5.1 with sdk manager

I even tried to create a new project with qt and I wrote the same code, I added the files yolov4 needs to run, and it compiles fine but I have the error when I execute the code.

Does anyone has an idea I am really stuck

Thanks.